# pycxsimulator TclError Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, pycxsimulator

**Trying to run this little piece of code on Ubuntu 14.04**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import pylab as PL
import random as RD
import scipy as SP

RD.seed()

populationSize = 100
noiseLevel = 1

def init():
    global time, agents

    time = 0

    agents = []
    for i in xrange(populationSize):
        newAgent = [RD.gauss(0, 1), RD.gauss(0, 1)]
        agents.append(newAgent)

def draw():
    PL.cla()
    x = [ag[0] for ag in agents]
    y = [ag[1] for ag in agents]
    PL.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    PL.axis('scaled')
    PL.axis([-100, 100, -100, 100])
    PL.title('t = ' + str(time))

def step():
    global time, agents

    time += 1

    for ag in agents:
        ag[0] += RD.gauss(0, noiseLevel)
        ag[1] += RD.gauss(0, noiseLevel)

import pycxsimulator
pycxsimulator.GUI().start(func=[init,draw,step])
```

**but got the following error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joaomeirelles/Documents/USP/TESE/exemplos/pycx-0.31/abm-randomwalk.py", line 49, in <module>
pycxsimulator.GUI().start(func=[init,draw,step])
  File "/home/joaomeirelles/Documents/USP/TESE/exemplos/pycx-0.31/pycxsimulator.py", line 48, in __init__
self.initGUI()
  File "/home/joaomeirelles/Documents/USP/TESE/exemplos/pycx-0.31/pycxsimulator.py", line 77, in initGUI
self.status.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='nswe')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1985, in grid_configure
+ self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

**does anyone know what could it be?**
I'v tried to use different versions of [Tcl/Tk](http://sourceforge.net/p/pymolapbsplugin/bugs/1/) (8.5 and 8.6) and to update [MGLTools](http://mgldev.scripps.edu/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1346), but none of them have worked.

thanks
JM

Comment: Why do you think this is a matplotlib issue?  The traceback is coming from what ever `pycxsimulator` is

Comment: The code you posted does not include the line that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 2):

I commented out line 75: #self.notebook.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5 ,side=TOP)
and line 78: #self.status.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=1, pady=1, expand=NO)

After that, the models I tried all worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, although this gets the programs to run, I believe it breaks the visualizations in pycx.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves
>   managed by pack

That means that somewhere in your code you're calling `.pack(...)` on a widget that is a child of the root window ("slaves managed by pack"), and later you're calling `.grid(...)` on another widget that is also a child of the root window ("cannot use geometry manager grid...").

Within any given container window (frame, root window, toplevel), all of the direct children can only be managed by grid OR pack, but not both.